# UWP App crashing when installing from Microsoft Store after adding windows.fullTrustProcess

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have added a Systray extension to my UWP project using this guide: https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/

The app can run in Debug and Release mode without issue, but after I package the app (`.appxupload`) and then upload it to the Microsoft Store, I then download it and install it, but it crashes immediately upon launch.

In Visual Studio, I go to `Debug > Other Debug Targets > Debug Installed App Package...`, and when I debug the app it only shows this error:

```
Activation of the Windows Store app 'MyApp!App' failed with error 'The target process aborted before activation completed. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.
Activation of the Windows Store app 'MyApp!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

Windows EventViewer just shows this:

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.22621.1555, time stamp: 0x235a45d0
Exception code: 0xe0434352
```

As the app is not executing any of my code, it is difficult to find the source of this problem. When the following code is removed from the `Package.appxmanifest` file, and then it is uploaded to the Microsoft store, it can be downloaded and installed successfully:

```
<Extensions>
    ...
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
        <uap:AppService Name="MyUWPExtensionService" />
    </uap:Extension>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Win32\SystemTrayComponent.exe" />
</Extensions>
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
    ...
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: I do not really understand this line; "then upload it to the Microsoft Store, I then download it and install it, but it crashes immediately upon launch"

You downloaded your app trough the windows store and then your app is crashing?

Comment: @RikudouEnSof Yes, after the update is published to the windows store, I then download the updated app, install it, and when I launch the app, it immediately crashes

Comment: Then I think we have a compatibility issue. UWP is great but not really compatible, especially because of its sandbox nature. It wants permission to OS features and abilities, looking at your windows partnership portal, is this crash persistent across all devices?

Comment: You can try to use Release mode, create a sideload package, and see if there is any problem with the local installation.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I previously tried that, and it could successfully run. It only crashes when downloaded & installed from the Microsoft Store. In an attempt to solve this issue, I created a Windows Application Packaging Project, and referenced both the UWP and Win32 projects from it. Earlier today I submitted that package to the Microsoft Store, but I'm just waiting on certification to complete. If that solves the issue, then I will post that as the answer.

Comment: Any progress recently? Has the certificate been authenticated?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Sorry for the late reply, yes using the Windows Application Packaging Project, and referencing both the UWP and Win32 projects solved the issue. The update was submitted to the store successfully and does not crash after downloading & installing the app now.